# number_with_precision adds zero to the number

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Assume `@total=100`. Then `number_with_precision(@total, :precision => 2)` returns `10000` instead of `100.00`.

We are running rails 3.2 and ruby 2.1. This helper method used to be fine. What causes the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `number_with_precision(@total, :precision => 2, :separator => '.')` might help?

Comment: Are you asking him/her to try that; or are you stating its an answer to his question? If its an answer, then please be a bit more assertive. Its hard to separate wheat from the chaff at times. Properly phrasing an answer will help users and moderators.

Comment: Hi. I'm pretty much new here. On one hand I am not meant to place answers as comments. On the other... am I only meant to answer when I feel completely sure of the answer being right?

Briefly: It was meant as an answer, however I can never know if it is legitimate, proper answer.

Comment: If you are not sure its an answer, then you should suggest it as a comment. You will be OK placing it in a comment. If its an answer and its wrong, then you could be downvoted and risk losing your points. If its an answer and you know its correct, then instruct the poster to use the code you present. Don't be bashful.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll try to let go of question marks in what I place as answers.